# Joomla : libraries mysql schema does not working for Insert records, add primary key, drop table command

Tags: joomla3.8

On extension update, instead of using update SQL schema I have given a custom button like fix database under that extension. It working fine. Custom script executes from same schema folder structure i.e. "/sql/updates/mysql"

But some DDL commands are not working like INSERT, ALTER for adding primary key for already existing table, DROP to delete table.

I have checked the MysqlChangeItem.php file (using Joomla 3.8.10) under "libraries/src/Schema/ChangeItem" & found the different DDL commands which are handled but does not found about INSERT/adding primary key for existing table/drop table.

Can you please suggest the solution

Comment: is anybody there to suggest a solution?

Comment: if anybody has any solution please revert back to me.